# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after th y are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to Node. I'm using express.js
There is a part of my code, where I'm trying to get data that I got from a form by AJAX and write this to variable `url`. I have `request.body`, but I can't pass it to "then". Instead of it, I have an error

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`

Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

```
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        return res.render('index.html').end();
    });

    app.post("/", jsonParser, function (request, response) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!request.body) {
                reject()
            } else {
                console.log(request.body);
                response.json(`${request.body.url}`);
                url = response.json(`${request.body.url}`);
                resolve(url);
            }
        }).then(data => console.log(data));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.json` is an express function that... [sends a Json response](http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.json).

You're calling it twice with

```
response.json(`${request.body.url}`);
url = response.json(`${request.body.url}`);
```

but you cannot do that, you cannot send two responses for one request.

Just remove the first line.